# Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Connect-AzAccount to set up your Azure credentials

Tags: azure, powershell

I want to connect PowerShell to Azure with the command Connect-AzAccount. I am connected successfully with a warning: *Unable to acquire token for tenant 'xxx'*.

When I run commenad Get-AzVM I have error message: *et-AzVM: Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Connect-AzAccount to set up your Azure credentials.*

Any tips and help please?

Comment: Try to use an interactive login to connect to a specific tenant: Connect-AzAccount -Tenant 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be possibility that your account is associated with the more than one tenant. In one of the tenant you may not have the desired permissions.

Rather than connecting to all the tenants, you could specify the tenant you would like to connect to :

```
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant <Your Tenant ID>
```

If you are still encountering the issue for your tenant as well. More likely there is a permission issue.I would suggest you reach out necessary stake holder (Tenant Admin for instance) to grant you the necessary permissions to run the powershell commandlet.